# lambda value threshold beyond which shrinkage penalty in glm is high and coefficients approach zero

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, lasso, ridge-regression

Conceptually, for both LASSO and ridge regression methods as lambda becomes "very large", the penalty impact grows and the coefficients approach zero. However,

a) is there a particular threshold for lambda beyond which this statement holds true?

b) Can we always infer that as lambda takes this very large value, that the coefficients will approach zero and as such, the number of predictors in the model will decrease?